# PHP - How to document a prepared statement as parameter

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a code snippet like this:

```
$pstmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
foo($pstmt);
```

Now I want to document the "foo" method, that a prepared statement is required.

But I only find `\mysqli_stmt` class.

BEGIN EDIT

A "more complete" example

```
$connection = pwm\MySQLHelper::getConnection();
$pstmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$pstmt->bind_param("s", $fbToken);
toJSON($pstmt);
$pstmt->close();
$connection->close();
```

And now the `toJSON($psm)` function (which is the `foo($ps)` from above

```
/**
* @param $data \mysqli_stmt A prepated statement
*/
function toJSON($pstmt)
{
  $pstmt->execute();
  $result = $pstmt->get_result();
  $rarray = [];
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $rarray[] = $row;
  }
  $result->close();
  echo json_encode($rarray);
}
```

The question is about the PHPDoc. I was unable to find a different class than "mysqli_stmt", but with this code PHPStorm does not recognize "execute()","get_result()","fetch_assoc()" and "close()".
I want to teach PHPStorm, that this is a prepared statement.

I hope the edit helped.

END EDIT

I am using PHPstorm and with `\mysqli_stmt` it is unable to find `execute()' and such.

tl;dr;

How to document a prepared statement as parameter, because `\mysqli_stmt` is not enough for PHPStorm.

Comment: Need better (more complete) example. For me (at least) it's not clear what exactly is required here (the context and what the problem is).

Comment: Do you mean for autocomplete?  If so 
   ` /**
     * @param \mysqli_stmt $statement
     */
    public function foo(\mysqli_stmt $statement)
    {
        
    }`
worked for me

Comment: Change `$data` to `$pstmt` in your PHPDoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of variable and name of the function's parameter don't match. In PHPDoc you have `$data` in function you have `$pstmt`. Change the PHPDoc from `$data` to `$pstmt`. After that it should work as expected.